Sum of asymptotically independent random variables - Convergence
Let $\theta_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \pi_i\cdot g_i$ where $0<\pi_i<1$ and $0<g_i<1/\pi_i$ such that $\theta_N\overset{N\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}\theta$.
If $X_i\sim Ber(\pi_i)$, I can easily show the convergence in mean square of the estimator:
$$
\hat{\theta}_N^*=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot g_i,
$$
which implies $\hat{\theta}_N^*-\theta_N\overset{ip}{\rightarrow}0$ for $N\rightarrow\infty$. Things get more complicated if the $g_i$'s are unknown.
Let $\mathcal{S}=\left\lbrace \sigma(X_i)\,:\, X_i=1,\, i=1,\dots,N\right\rbrace$ of size $|\mathcal{S}|=n$, i.e. the set of units such that $X_i=1$.
Assume I can get consistent estimators of $g_i$ from the units in $\mathcal{S}$, such that  $\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})\overset{ip}{\rightarrow} g_i$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$.
I can get a plug-in estimate as:
$$
\hat{\theta}_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S}).
$$
Is there anything I can conclude about the convergence of $\hat{\theta}_N-\theta_N$ to $0$?
Considering that $\frac{n}{N}\rightarrow\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N\pi_i}{N}$ we should have $n\overset{N\rightarrow\infty}{\rightarrow}\infty$.
My hunch is that the convergence of $\hat{\theta}_N-\theta_N\overset{ip}{\rightarrow}0$ (or even a.s.) should hold through a Law of Large Numbers argument, but I am not entirely sure as the $X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})$ are only asymptotically independent.
If necessary, further restrictions on $\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})$ might be assumed (e.g. $\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})<\nu$ so that the Bounded Convergence Theorem holds)?
MY GUESS
My idea, which I am not entirely confident about, is the following.

Slutsky theorem. $X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})\overset{id}{\rightarrow}X_i\cdot g_i$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$
Bounded convergence theorem. Let $0<\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})<\nu$, hence $0<X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})<\nu$, so that limit and sum/expectation operator can be exchanged
Continuous Mapping Theorem. Given that $X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})\overset{id}{\rightarrow}X_i\cdot g_i$ then $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})\overset{id}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot g_i$$
Convergence in probabilitu of the last term is trivial provided that 2. holds

Passage 3. is what disturbs me, as the convergence in distribution is on $n$ that grows at the same rate of $N$...

Re "easily show" at the outset: How? That expression needn't converge in any sense.  Let $g_i=i/\pi_i$ for instance.

How can you get consistent estimators of the $g_i$ from $S$?  You have exactly one observation per $i$, so there's no  "$n$" that can $\to \infty$.

@jbowman each $g_i$ is estimated from the whole sample $\mathcal{S}$ and the $n$ of the sample does go to $+\infty$

@whuber you are correct I did not state in advance that I know for a fact the original series is convergent. Even if not, what I am really interested about is $\hat{\theta}_N$ getting closer to $\theta_N$ as $N$ increases, i.e. $\hat{\theta}_N-\theta_N\rightarrow 0$.


Your sample size is $N$, the number of $g_i$ is $N$, so you have one observation per $g_i$ no matter how large $N$ is.  2. You have given us no reason to suppose there is any information in $X_{j\neq i}$ that is relevant to the estimation of $g_i$.   $g_i$ could have completely random/arbitrary values.  The only observation relevant to estimating each $g_i$ in this setup is $X_i$.


@jbowman that is the case. $X_{j\neq i}$ have information also for $g_i$, hence the information can be pooled to get consistent estimators for each i. I have been trying to give only the necessary information and I am sorry if it is not fully convincing, just take the consistency as an assumption.

@jbowman imagine $\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})$ is a prediction for unit $i$ from a model (the true model) trained on all $\mathcal{S}$

Please verify the following: a) the $g_i$ (the true ones) are constants. b) The way I understand the definition of the set $\mathcal S$, it contains the index numerical value of the positions that the $X_i=1$ occupy in the $X$ sequence, i.e. if we have ${X_1=1, X_2 = 0 , X_3=1}$ we get up to here $\mathcal{S} = {1,3}$. This means that the value of its maximal element will go to infinity as $N \to \infty$. Do I understand correctly?

@AlecosPapadopoulos
a) Yes, the true $g_i$'s are constants. b) You are right about the definition of which units end up in $\mathcal{S}$, but the index is not of interest per-sè.  So, in your example, the units $1$ and $3$ are in $\mathcal{S}$ and I can use information available on those sampled units to estimate $\hat{g}_1$ and $\hat{g}_3$. The notation $\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})$ is to make explicit how the estimate depends on the whole sample: each $\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})$ is a function of other (given, not random) information available only on the sampled units.

Ok, but then, they way you wrote the definition of $\mathcal S$ is misleading. Keeping with my example in reality $\mathcal S = {X_1, X_3}$ and not ${1,3}$. If this is the case then $\mathcal S = {X_i: X_i =1, i=1,...,N}$ would be a suitable definition - or even  $\mathcal S = {\sigma(X_i): X_i =1, i=1,...,N}$ where $\sigma$ denotes a sigma algebra or an information set.

@AlecosPapadopoulos thanks for pointing that out. The second definition is the one I was looking for. Editing it right now.

We want to examine the limiting behavior in probability of
$$\hat{\theta}_N - \theta_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S}) - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \pi_i\cdot g_i$$
Before going to infinity, we add and subtract,
$$\hat{\theta}_N - \theta_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot \hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S}) + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot {g}_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot {g}_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \pi_i\cdot g_i$$
$$\implies \hat{\theta}_N - \theta_N = \hat{\theta}_N^* - \theta_N + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot [\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})-g_i].$$
Since we know that $\hat{\theta}_N^* - \theta_N \to_p 0$, to obtain $\hat{\theta}_N - \theta_N \to_p 0$ we need
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\cdot [\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})-g_i] \to_p 0.$$
This is Law of Large Numbers territory. Because the members of the sequence $\{X_i\cdot [\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})-g_i]\}$ are not identically distributed, and also, are not independent for finite $N$, we need Markov's LLN, to be able to claim that this sample mean converges to the arithmetic average of the expected values of the elements.
Set for the moment $W_i \equiv X_i\cdot [\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})-g_i]$.
The condition for Markov's theorem to hold is
$$\frac 1 {N^2}{\rm Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^NW_i\right) \to 0, \quad N\to \infty.$$
We have
$$\frac 1 {N^2}{\rm Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^NW_i\right) = \frac 1{N^2} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N{\rm Var}(W_i)\right) + \frac 1 {N^2} \left(\sum \sum\right)_{i\neq j} {\rm Cov}(W_i, W_j).$$
So you need

A condition that guarantees that the variance of all $X_i\cdot [\hat{g_i}(\mathcal{S})-g_i]$ is bounded. Since $X_i$ is bounded you need $\hat{g_i}(\mathcal{S})-g_i$ to be bounded also. If so, the first term in the RHS of the condition goes to zero.

A condition on the covariances -essentially we need the "average covariance" to go to zero. Now, for any given $N$ there are $N(N-1)$ covariance terms (of various magnitudes in principle). And their sum is divided by $N^2$ which is of the same order than their cardinality. So eventually, the only way that this sum of covariances will stay away from zero is that only a finite number of them goes to zero. But, on the contrary, because by the premises we have that $\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S}) \to_p g_i$, we get that all of them go to zero. Hence their sum, divided by $N^2$, will go to zero.


So given a boundedness restriction on $\hat{g_i}(\mathcal{S})$ (the $g_i$s are finite constants), it appears that Markov condition is satisfied. Then the component of interest will behave in probability at the limit as
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N E\Big[X_i\cdot (\hat{g}^*_i(\mathcal{S})-g_i)\Big],$$
where $\hat{g}^*_i(\mathcal{S})$ is the probability limit of $\hat{g_i}(\mathcal{S})$. But since we have by the premises that $\hat{g}^*_i(\mathcal{S}) = g_i$, the expression above will be zero and so,
$$(\hat{\theta}_N - \theta_N) = (\hat{\theta}_N^* - \theta_N) + o_p(1) \to_p 0$$

Thank you for your complete and extremely helpful answer. Those covariances have been bothering me since the beginning and Markov's Theorem is indeed the way to proceed!

I know for a fact $0<g_i<1/\pi_i$ and I can enforce $0<\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})<1/\nu$: these two would imply $1/\min_i(\pi_i)<W_i<1/\nu$ and 1) holds.  About 2), isn't the convergence in probability of $\hat{g_i}$ to $g_i$ a sufficient condition for the covariances to die out? By Slutsky and Cont. Mapping Theorem $W_i\rightarrow X_i\cdot 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[W_i\cdot W_j]\rightarrow 0$


*$-1/\min_i(\pi_i)<W_i<1/\nu$

The leading terms of the sequence of ${\hat{g}_i(\mathcal{S})}$ certainly become less and less dependent on anything since they gradually become a constant. But the Markov condition wants the average pair-wise covariance over all elements  of the sequence to go to zero: it is a sum and includes ${\rm Cov}(\hat{g}1(\mathcal{S}), \hat{g}2(\mathcal{S}))$, as well as  ${\rm Cov}(\hat{g}1(\mathcal{S}), \hat{g}{20000}(\mathcal{S}))$, as well as ${\rm Cov}(\hat{g}{200000}(\mathcal{S}), \hat{g}{5}(\mathcal{S}))$, etc So it is about the rate, or the form, of convergence that is needed here.

But the convergence of $\hat{g}i(\mathcal{S})\overset{ip}{\rightarrow} g_i$ holds $\forall, i$ for $n=|\mathcal{S}|$ approaching infinity.
What I mean is that for $n\rightarrow \infty$ then  $\hat{g}1(\mathcal{S})\rightarrow g_1$ just as much as $\hat{g}{2000}(\mathcal{S})\rightarrow g{2000}$. Therefore, all terms in those covariances shall approach $0$, shan't they?

I see your point that it is an infinite sum: the sequence going to 0 does not ensure that the series converges. However, we here have that each single term of the sequence converges to 0. I think this should be sufficient, but I am not entirely sure. Will look into it, thanks for your help.

Yes, it is sufficient. Adjusted my answer accordingly.

I sketched that same adjustment on paper yesterday morning! Your help has been extremely valuable. Thank you so much. If things go as they should, I will get back to you for acknowledgments. Wish you all the best
